# Where is the heartbeat sensor for the PKP pecheneg?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I use a PKP pecheneg a lot in MW3 (multiplayer) and I can't seem to find the heartbeat sensor attachment for it. Could someone help me please?

Comment: This might be a bug. Also note that, all Juggernauts in Survival mode carry this weapon and they do not drop it when killed. I'll be waiting on an official patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you can read [in this wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/PKP_Pecheneg), there's no Heartbeat Sensor available:

> - Red Dot Sight - Unlocked at weapon level 2.
> - Silencer - Unlocked at weapon level 5.
> - Grip - Unlocked at weapon level 8.
> - ACOG Scope - Unlocked at weapon level 11.
> - Rapid Fire - Unlocked at weapon level 14.
> - Heartbeat Sensor **(with glitch only)**
> - Holographic Sight - Unlocked at weapon level 22.
> - Extended Mags - Unlocked at weapon level 25.
> - Thermal Scope - Unlocked at weapon level 27.

and...

> The PKP Pecheneg is one of the few LMGs that **can't accept the
>   Heartbeat Sensor in Multiplayer** (the PKP Pecheneg can only be seen
>   with a Heartbeat Sensor in the Campaign mission "Return to Sender",
>   also, that PKP Pecheneg can't be picked up).

i can't find any information about that noted "glitch" and never heard of this before - but even if this is possible, i wouldn't recommend to use this glich because of the risk of [being banned](http://www.cdlc-clan.com/inc/images/uploads/picupload/datei_1323859161.jpg)...